# Getting error when trying to start windows service through Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services

So I am trying to use Powershell to start a windows service. I have the service installed just fine, but when I call `Start-Service -Name $name` I am recieving the following error.

`Start-Service : Service 'IncidentManagementService (IncidentManagementService)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service IncidentManagementService on computer '.'.`

I have powershell running as an Administrator and I also tried going under the properties of the .exe file and checking "run as admin" to no avail.

If anyone could give me a clear reason as to why the service is not starting it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to start the services fine from the UI (services.msc)?

Comment: From the Computer Management services screen? I tried running from there and I received Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start request in a timely fashion

Comment: @Foster In that case, have you looked at the event log?

Comment: [Troubleshoot with the event log](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DiagnoseProblems)

Comment: please check this answer, may it help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651152/cannot-start-service-on-computer

Answer (score 0):

In my case the service is disabled... so is the reason I am getting that error.